# Post Method Request/Form Submission

Tags: perl, form-submit, web-scraping

I've been working on this for the past few hours, and after going through tons of Google results, I still can't get it to work.

I'm writing a perl script that connects to https://web5.uottawa.ca/rezweb/search.php, selects either "Off/On-Campus Accomodation", clicks search, and prints the results.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/user/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use Crypt::SSLeay; #Since it's HTTPS

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $url = 'https://web5.uottawa.ca/rezweb/search.php';
my $formdata = ['accomodationType' => '1', 'submit' => 'Search'];

my $response = $ua->post($url, $formdata);
die "Error: ", $response->status_line . "\n"
  unless $response->content;
```

Unfortunately, it's still the page source of the form--not the search results page.

Comment: have a look at `WWW::Mechanize`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related extra doc: [Mojo::DOM](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mojo%3a%3aDOM;).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Mojo::DOM;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $url = 'https://web5.uottawa.ca/rezweb/search.php';
my $formdata = [
                accomodationType => 1,
                maximum => 9999,
                maximumOnCampus => 9999,
                minimum => 0,
                minimumOnCampus => 0,
                "search_op[]" => 5,
                "search_op[]" => 6,
                "search_op[]" => 7,
                "search_op[]" => 8,
                "search_op[]" => 9,
                "search_op[]" => 10,
                "search_op[]" => 11,
                srch_rental_type4 => "on",
                srch_rental_type5 => "on",
                submit => "Search",
                zone => 0,
                ];

my $response = $ua->post($url, $formdata);
die "Error: ", $response->status_line, "\n"
    unless $response->content;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $response->decoded_content );
my @matches = map { $_->parent->parent }
    grep { $_->attrs("href") =~ /search\.php\?id=\d+/ }
    $dom->find("tr > td > a")->each;

for my $row ( @matches ) {
    print $row->all_text, $/;
}

__END__

157 Laurier Ave E 1 Hyman Soloway Sublet 1 bedroom 0400 01/08/2011
75 Louis Pasteur Pvt 1 Brooks Sublet 1 bedroom 0650 01/08/2011
75 Louis Pasteur Pvt 1 Brooks Sublet 1 bedroom 0750 25/07/2011
```

I arrived at the POST parameter list by turning off JS—their site uses it for enhancement—and inspecting the request. While this solution works, it’s fragile. Make sure that you’re not violating the site’s ToS or abusing the form by hammering it.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two paths to choose from: hardcode the particular form values you want and use LWP::UserAgent to pass them as the post data (adding an arrayref parameter to POST() - see the [HTTP::Request::Common](http://p3rl.org/HTTP%3a%3aRequest%3a%3aCommon#POST) documentation), or use its subclass [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize), which will provide you methods to get the blank form, enter values its fields, submit the form, and get the result.

Either way can break due to changes to the website; it's up to you to decide which is more likely and which seems easier to code.

You aren't using any LWP::Simple functionality; you should remove its `use`.

Update:

When I went to the page and selected off-campus accomodation, it adds a bunch more (optional) form fields; posting at that point sends these parameters:

```
accomodationType    1
maximum 9999
maximumOnCampus 9999
minimum 0
minimumOnCampus 0
submit  Search
zone    0
```

Using all these parameters will work.

Comment: Thanks; I've read through the documentation, and found a few examples online, but I'm still having a problem (see above, I've edited my original post).